# Which jutsu was White Fang strongest at?

Tags: naruto

What was the real strength of the White Fang (Kakashi's father)? Was he good at taijutsu, nin, or any other jutsu?

Answer (score 3):

According to [his Naruto Wiki article](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sakumo_Hatake#Abilities), he was

> ...proficient in kenjutsu, his reputation as "Konoha's White Fang" stemming from his extensive use of the White Light Chakra Sabre, which emitted a streak of white chakra when swung.

The citation for this is Chapter 242, page 12.

Comment: It should be noted that nowhere in the manga, not even in that chapter of Kakashi Gaiden, is mentioned that Sakumo Hatake was especially gifted in kenjutsu. What is said in 242 is that he was known for using that custom short blade of chakra-sensitive metal, and that said blade glows white when it is infused with chakra. It is said time and time that he was an exceptionally strong ninja, but no specialty is ever mentioned (not even that he might have been good at standard ninja training, for instance).